# js.chart com erro em *ngIf

Tags: angular

Estou tentando implementar um gráfico js.chart em um ng-template vinculado a uma diretiva *ngIf, mas quando nesta condição o gráfico não abre e gera o erro *can't acquire context from the given item.*

Alguém já passou por esse problema?

**.TS**

```
export class PesquisahistorianComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('chart', {static: true}) chart: Chart = [];

....

  async ngOnInit() {

    ...

    await this.geraToken();
    await this.retornaPesquisa();
  }


public retornaPesquisa = async () => {
    await this._api.getValuesIfix(this.tokenFinal, this._stringPost).then(returnpesq => {
      this.dadosPesquisa = returnpesq['Data'];
      this.dadosTabela = this.dadosPesquisa[0].Samples;

      this._graflabels = this.dadosTabela.map(function (e) {
        return e.TimeStamp;
      });
      this._grafdata = this.dadosTabela.map(function (e) {
        return e.Value;
      });

      this.chart = new Chart('chart', {  
        type: 'line',  
        data: {  
          labels: this._graflabels,  

          datasets: [  
            {  
              data: this._grafdata,  
              borderColor: '#3cb371',  
              backgroundColor: "#0000FF",  
            }  
          ]  
        },  
        options: {  
          legend: {  
            display: false  
          },  
          scales: {  
            xAxes: [{  
              display: true  
            }],  
            yAxes: [{  
              display: true  
            }],  
          }  
        }  
      });  

      this.isLoading = false;
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

**.HTML**

```
<div>
  <h3>Pesquisa dados operacionais - Base Histórica</h3>
</div>

<ng-template #rodape>
  <mat-card style="width: 90%">
    <div *ngFor="let data of dadosPesquisa">
      <p>{{data.TagName}}</p>
      <p>De: {{_dataI  | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} - 00:00 a {{_dataF  | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} - 23:59</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tabela-container">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dadosTabela" class="mat-elevation-z8">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="dia">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Dia </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.TimeStamp  | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="hora">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Hora </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.TimeStamp  | date:'HH:mm'}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Value">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Valor </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Value | number : '.2-2'}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Quality">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Qualidade </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <div *ngIf="element.Quality != 3; else outrovalor">
              Bad
            </div>
            <ng-template #outrovalor>
              Good
            </ng-template>
          </td>
          <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> </td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="colunasTabela"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: colunasTabela;"></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </mat-card>
  <br>
  <mat-card style="width: 45%">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center"><h4>Resumo</h4></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Máximo:</th>
        <td style="text-align: center"> {{_dadosMax | number : '.2-2'}} </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Média:</th>
        <td style="text-align: center"> {{_dadosMed | number : '.2-2'}} </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Mínimo:</th>
        <td style="text-align: center"> {{_dadosMin | number : '.2-2'}} </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </mat-card>
  <mat-card style="width: 90%">
    <canvas id="chart">{{ chart }}</canvas>    
</mat-card>
</ng-template>

<div class="container4" *ngIf="isLoading; else rodape">
  <mat-progress-spinner color="primary" mode="indeterminate">
  </mat-progress-spinner>
  <br><br>Aguarde<br>Gerando tabela de dados...
</div>
```

**Ps:** o HTML está sem formatação (trata-se de um teste).

Comment: posta seu codigo

Comment: agora com o código.

Comment: Tive problemas nesse sentido e optei por usar a biblioteca: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts que se baseia no https://www.chartjs.org/

Comment: Creio que o this .charts seja undefined no momento que vc chama ele não?

Comment: Pelo que consegui pesquisar esse problema com o ngif parece ser comum, vou testar o ng2-charts.